# is system(const char *command) lead to cpu sys 100%

Tags: linux-kernel, system, cpu-usage, system-calls

I create one background thread B,and in func of B,

```
void func()
{
  system('gzip -f text-file'); // size of text-file is 100M
  xxx
}
```

I found sometime the sys of one cpu(my server has more than one cpu core） is 100%.
strace the progress, I found clone syscall consume more than 3 seconds, which is almost execution time of gzip.

```
**17:46:04.545159** clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|SIGCHLD, parent_tidptr=0x418dba38) = 39169
**17:46:07.432385** wait4(39169, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 39169
```

so my question is,
1. is system('gzip -f text-file'） lead to 100% cpu sys ?
2. what is the root cause

Comment: the possible reason maybe clone will copy memory structure of parent process. sys_clone -> do_fork -> copy_process -> dup_mm -> dup_mmap. In my experiment, rss of parent is 60G, about 2000 mmap entry.

Comment: The guess above is right. copy_page_range consume most of time, and when the rss of process is large, the execution time is linearly increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sys_clone` without `CLONE_MM` does full copy of virtual memory mapping from parent process into child process, according to https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand021.html

```
343      Allocate a new mm
348-350  Copy the parent mm and initialise the process specific mm fields with init_mm()
352-353  Initialise the MMU context for architectures that do not automatically manage their MMU
355-357  Call dup_mmap() which is responsible for copying all the VMAs regions in use by the parent process
```

VMA count for process with 60GB in 2000 mmaps is high, and `dup_mm` may take lot of time.

You want to do small external run (`gzip`), but the fork is not best solution for such large programs. All copies of vma will be trashed by doing `exec`: http://landley.net/writing/memory-faq.txt

> For example, the fork/exec combo creates transient virtual memory usage
>     spikes, which go away again almost immediately without ever breaking the
>     copy on write status of most of the pages in the forked page tables.  Thus
>     if a large process forks off a smaller process, enormous physical memory
>     demands threaten to happen (as far as overcommit is concerned), but never
>     materialize.

So, it can be better for you to:

- check vfork+exec pair (aka `posix_spawn`), which will suspend your huge process for small time, until child will do `exec` or `exit)
- create separate helper process before doing all the 60GB of mmaps; communicate with it using pipes/sockets/ipc/anything. Helper process is small and will sleep most time on ipc. When you needs `gzip`, you just asks helper to run it.
- or integrate compression into your program. Gzip and bzip2 both has good libraries, `zlib` and `libbz2`, and there are wrappers in boost.